# android ProgressDialog fontSize change

Tags: android, progressdialog, font-size

Is it possible to change the font size and make text bold which is displayed in a `ProgressDialog` .I have created a `ProgressDialog` like this:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "Heading","Message...", true);
```

I want to make **Heading** bold and **increase** the font size..pls help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `import android.text.Html;` then you will be able to use the `Html.fromHtml()` method to do it, like so:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, Html.fromHtml(
               "<b>Heading<b>"), Html.fromHtml("<big>Message...</big>"), true);
```

You should also be able to use other Html text formatting tags like `<small>` `<u>` `<i>` `<sub>` etc., and obviously you can mix and match them like any other html text.

Comment: As a note, if importing strings from XML, don't forget to write your HTML tags using HTML Entities, for example: `code`<b>Heading</b> becomes &lt;b&gt;Heading&lt;/b&gt;`code`. More on HTML Entities here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: nice very nice,   I think its gonna help me alot