# Is there an easy way to change textsize in ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog, text-size

I'm looking for an easy way to change the textsize in a ProgressDialog. I know that I could create a custom progressdialog, but is there any other easier solution for this?

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043140/progressdialog-change-text-size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043140/progressdialog-change-text-size. check my answer using spannable string

Comment: I have found this solution already, but it seems me not a good way or a also complicated way.

Comment: but maybe the easiest solution anyway. hm. thanks.

Comment: Then you better go with custom progress box on top your layout.

Comment: check this out using android.text.html fromHtml() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595390/android-progressdialog-fontsize-change

Comment: Also found this solution. But now I do it with the SpannableString. Thanks.